Hyperparameter tuning for small datasets
I have about 10 small imbalanced datasets (some of them only have about 150 samples). I want to try a bunch of balancing techniques on some models. For that, I'm using the repeated stratified cross-validation and reporting the average performance metrics as done in many research papers. The thing is, I'm doing this without tuning the hyperparameters (because the datasets are too small), so it made sense at first as the goal is to compare the models+balancing techniques to the baseline models, but the results I got made me think that hyperparameters tuning is a must.
I know I can't do the tuning on the dataset and then fit and predict on the same one because of overfitting, and it's not the right way to go about it. I can't split the data either because of its size. I've thought about nested cross-validation, but again, I'll be splitting the dataset further, and I can't afford that. And I still need to perform the repeated stratified cross-validation for performance evaluation. So, how can I proceed?

"'I've thought about nested cross-validation, but again, I'll be splitting the dataset further, and I can't afford that." This is about dataset size, not speed, isn't it? But then if you do nested leave one out CV, you only lose one more observation one step down.

"I want to try a bunch of balancing techniques on some models." why do you want to do that?  Using models without hyper-parameter tuning is not a good idea (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06777.pdf) so it is good that you want to tune them.  This is especially true for small datasets where getting the regularisation right is very important.  You need nested cross-validation to get an unbiased performance estimate (https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf) so that is also the right thing to do. (note I am the common author on those two papers)

Christian Hennig's suggestion is a good one (+1), note for many machine learning methods, leave-one-out cross-validation can be performed cheaply as a byproduct of fitting the model, so I often use it as the basis for model tuning. If you have very small datasets, balancing may not help very much, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he/559317#559317 BTW leave-one-out CV is going to be almost stratified as you have only disturbed the balance by one pattern, so it is probably O.K. from that perspective.

Thank you so much Christian and Dikran for your insights. To clarify, I'm experimenting with balancing techniques because this is the topic of my internship and we want to see how it works for different kinds of data. I'm a beginner, so I still have the following questions if you can help please:

If I perform the nested loo CV, will I still be able to implement it in a repeated manner (repeated CV) to ensure that results aren't random and for more robustness? I was initially perfoming repeated stratified 10-fold CV 5 times.



I'll probably have to add more datasets to these 10 small datasets, and the number of samples in the new ones ranges between 900 and 5000. Would it still be a good idea to go for loo CV?
@Dikran what do you mean by performing the CV cheaply as a byproduct of fitting the model? It would be really helpful if you can give a (code) example.
Thank you so much, I appreciate it.


" we want to see how it works for different kinds of data." for small datasets, it is likely that it doesn't help much as you don't have enough data to judge how much balancing you need to offset any bias against the minority class.  Here is an example of virtual LOOCV for kernel logistic regression that I did some time ago ( https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-008-5055-9 ) but similar approaches work for a variety of models - this one is similar to standard results for ordinary logistic regression.
